# Умножить два 64-битных числа и поделить на третье

Tags: c, алгоритм, арифметика

Есть ли быстрый способ найти значения этих выражений, используя 64-битные целочисленные переменные?

```
x * 2**64 / 10**19
(x * 2**64) % 10**19
```

где `0 <= x < 10**19`, `**`— возведение в степень. Нельзя использовать вещественные числа и переменные размером больше 64 бит.

Comment: У вас числа целые? Результат тоже хотите целый?
Лучше объясните, что вы делаете. Потому что делаете вы что-то странное.

Comment: @gbg Да, x - целое и результат деления тоже.

Comment: А теперь объясните, какой результат вы хотите получить. Потому как итог деления 64 битного целого на 10^19 - это практически всегда 0

Comment: @gbg тут не одно число, а произведение двух 64-битных чисел, `x` и `2**64`.

Comment: `2**64` это не 64-битное число. Задача у вас сводится к `{hi=x, lo=0} / {hi=0, lo=10**19}` (деление двух 128бит. чисел, каждое состоящих из двух 64бит. половинок). Если [скомпилировать деление 128](https://goo.gl/L5Qr9s), то видно что встроенные функции компилятор может использовать, например, [`tu_int
__udivmodti4(tu_int a, tu_int b, tu_int* rem)`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/fce320da7a80b1b0f2d1228b9be6a83280315d40/lib/builtins/udivmodti4.c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 2<sup>64</sup> / 10<sup>19</sup> = 2<sup>45</sup> / 5<sup>19</sup>,

**2<sup>45</sup> = 9*5<sup>18</sup> + 3490*5<sup>12</sup> + 2938*5<sup>6</sup> + 10707,**

**2<sup>45</sup> / 5<sup>19</sup> = 9/5 + 3490/5<sup>7</sup> + 2938/5<sup>13</sup> + 10707/5<sup>19</sup>**.

2. **x = 5<sup>19</sup>r +q**, 
   где **r = x / 5<sup>19</sup>; q = x % 5<sup>19</sup>, q<5<sup>19</sup>**.
3. В первом случае:

(x*2<sup>64</sup>)/10<sup>19</sup> = ((5<sup>19</sup>r +q) * 2<sup>45</sup>) / 5<sup>19</sup>,

**(x*2<sup>64</sup>)/10<sup>19</sup>  = 2<sup>45</sup>r + r<sub>0</sub> + r<sub>1</sub> + r<sub>2</sub> +r<sub>3</sub>**,

**r<sub>0</sub> = (9q) / 5; q<sub>0</sub> = (9q) % 5;

r<sub>1</sub> = (q<sub>0</sub>5<sup>6</sup> + 3490q) / 5<sup>7</sup>; q<sub>1</sub> = (q<sub>0</sub>5<sup>6</sup> + 3490q) % 5<sup>7</sup>;

r<sub>2</sub> = (q<sub>1</sub>5<sup>6</sup> + 2938q) / 5<sup>13</sup>; 
q<sub>2</sub> = (q<sub>1</sub>5<sup>6</sup> + 2938q) % 5<sup>13</sup>;

r<sub>3</sub> = (q<sub>2</sub>5<sup>6</sup> + 10707q) / 5<sup>19</sup>;**

4. Bo втором случае можно выносить общий множитель:

(x*2<sup>64</sup>) % 10<sup>19</sup> = 2<sup>19</sup>((5<sup>19</sup>r +q)*2<sup>45</sup>) % 5<sup>19</sup>) = 2<sup>19</sup>((q*2<sup>45</sup>) % 5<sup>19</sup>),

**(x*2<sup>64</sup>) % 10<sup>19</sup> = 2<sup>19</sup>(5<sup>18</sup>((9q) % 5) + 5<sup>12</sup>((3490q) % 5<sup>7</sup>) + 5<sup>6</sup>((2938q) % 5<sup>13</sup>) + 10707q) %5<sup>19</sup>).**

Алгоритм линейный, проблемы с программой исключены.

Пусть x = 2 345 678 912 345 678 912 = 122 981 * 5<sup>19</sup> + 2 490 226 538 287,
r = 122 981, q = 2 490 226 538 287.

Прямые вычисления дают
**(1) = 4 327 013 857 513 811 925,

(2) = 9 969 087 398 626 721 792.**

Вычисления по предложенному алгоритму дают:

2<sup>45</sup>r = 4 327 009 263 856 648 192;
r<sub>0</sub> = 4 482 407 768 916, q<sub>0</sub> = 3;
r<sub>1</sub> = 111 243 399 918, q<sub>1</sub> = 74 755;
r<sub>2</sub> = 5 993 502, q<sub>1</sub> = 116 440 331;
r<sub>3</sub> = 1 397,

**(1): 4 327 013 857 513 811 925;**

**(2):** 2<sup>19</sup>((5<sup>18</sup>*3 + 5<sup>12</sup>*27 880 + 5<sup>6</sup>*169 096 581 + 17 195 145 048 284) % 5<sup>19</sup>) = 2<sup>19</sup>(((3*15 625 + 27 880)*15 625 + 169 096 581) *15 625 + 17 195 145 048 284) % 5<sup>19</sup>) = **9 969 087 398 626 721 792**.

Comment: Спасибо, но ваш способ не проходит тесты. Например для `x=2345678912345678912`. Мой способ, в принципе, похож на этот.

Comment: @Imieee Всё работает, спасибо за тестирование.

Comment: Действительно, работает и быстрее, чем мой способ! Можно слегка улучшить, если убрать `9 * 5**18` (тогда будет `144115 * 5**12`). Ещё немного странно, что если остаток посчитать как `q3 * 2**19`, то будет медленнее.

Comment: @Imieee Да, за разрядную сетку не вылезаем.

Answer (score 9):

Творчески переработав Уоррена, вот такая функция для вашего деления и получения остатка:

```
unsigned long long divlu(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long * rem)
{
    unsigned long long y = 0ll, z = 10000000000000000000ull, t;
    long long i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 64; ++i)
    {
        t = (long long)x >> 63;
        x = (x << 1)| (y >> 63);
        y <<= 1;
        if ((x|t) >= z)
        {
            x -= z;
            ++y;
        }
    }
    if (rem) *rem = x;
    return y;
}
```

Передаете в нее свой `x`, и получаете на выходе частное, а в `rem` - делитель...

Выборочная проверка с длинной арифметикой подтверждает корректность.

**Update**
Полный код для общего случая деления 128-битного `xy` (т.е. понятно, что в `x` - старшие 64 бита, в `y` - младшие) на 64-битное `z`:

```
unsigned long long divlu(unsigned long long x, 
                         unsigned long long y,
                         unsigned long long z,
                         unsigned long long * rem)
{
    unsigned long long t;
    long long i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 64; ++i)
    {
        t = (long long)x >> 63;
        x = (x << 1)| (y >> 63);
        y <<= 1;
        if ((x|t) >= z)
        {
            x -= z;
            ++y;
        }
    }
    if (rem) *rem = x;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: А можно источник, откуда вы взяли эту функцию? Как-то не очень понятно, как она работает.

Comment: Уоррен, "Алгоритмические трюки для программистов", у него рассматривается деление 64-битного на 32-битное; ну, я немного подкорректировал :)

Comment: Интересно, минус - в очередных педагогических целях, типа, нельзя писать код для того, кто его сам не написал? :)

Comment: я вам наоборот поставил плюс)

Comment: Не только вы - трое поставили плюс, и кто-то минус.

Comment: Красивое решение !

Comment: Думаю, можно оптимизировать, например, сократить на `2**19` (тогда цикл выполняется 45 раз), убрать `| (y >> 63);`. Ещё вроде бы битовые сдвиги отрицательных чисел — UB (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer). Ну и конечно, по сути это поразрядное длинное деление. Я думал, есть что-то более «хитрое»...

Comment: @Harry, я минус не лепил, но плюс точно не поставлю. Причина: отсуствие тестов.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, если вы не верите мне на слово "Выборочная проверка с длинной арифметикой подтверждает корректность", то, надеюсь, у вас хватит умения написать их самостоятельно? Ну, а я тогда поставлю плюс вам :)

Comment: @Harry, для начала неплохо бы понять, как ввести произведение двух чисел, одно из которых 128-битное. Надеюсь вам не надо рассказывать, что 2^64/10**19 будет примерно 1 (~1.8 если думать о дробной части). И ваш код смысл теряет.

Comment: @0andriy Ну, во-первых, оба 64-битные, во вторых, это конкретное умножение - на конкретно же 2^64, так что это просто 128 байт, старшие 64 которого - `x`, а младшие - нулевые... Неужели это не очевидно? Для проверки я использовал MAPM. 1000 случайных 64-битных значений x дали одинаковые результаты. А вообще, простите уж, но конкретно ваша критика всегда сводится к "не знаю как, но знаю, что не так". Покажите, что приведенный код не работает, а потом говорите о том, имеет он смысл или нет. Как я понимаю, с вас, если бы я привел проверку, станется потребовать все 10^19 совпадений привести :)

Comment: @0andriy я протестировал в составе большей программы, и оригинальный вариант из ответа, и исправленный, все тесты прошли. Хотя конечно, мне тоже не сразу стало ясно, как эта функция работает.

Comment: @Harry, неплохо бы уточнить в тексте ответа (или комментариями к аргументам в коде), в `x` старшие или младшие биты 128-бит числа (и заодно уж, дать код для умножения 2-х 64-бит чисел). Кстати, а с знаковыми числами этот код будет правильно работать?

Comment: Как ни странно, но этот способ даже медленней, чем мой первоначальный «наивный вариант»! Цикл с 64 итерациями срабатывает за 19 секунд, цикл с 45 — за 13, первоначальный вариант за 3.

Comment: @avp в `x` -- старшие биты, для отрицательных чисел, мне кажется, код из ответа работать не будет, так как `t` всегда 1.

Comment: @avp Как указано в сигнатуре, это для беззнаковых чисел. Но заметим, что в условии было ограничение 0 <= x < 10**19.

Comment: Даже только для беззнаковых эта функция практически бесполезна. Она работает, только если делимое достаточно мало или делитель достаточно велик, т.е. результат деления должен поместится в 64 бита (очевидно, что с остатком проблем не возникает).

Comment: @avp Я же нисколько не возражаю, я даже соглашусь, что команду процессора `div` разработали кретины из Intel, потому что она практически бесполезна по тем же причинам. Непонятно только, почему никто не написал свой алгоритм и не предложил его Уоррену для следующего издания книги, а ТС - для решения его задачи...

Comment: Да ладно, вам... Если кому-то понадобится, то несколько минут гугления выводят, например, [вот сюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/785014/UInt-Division-Modulus)

Comment: Эмуляция длинных вычислений интересна, но не соответствует поставленному вопросу.